# Image not loading in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

I can view my image from direct URL apply in src tag but if I tried load as dynamically it's throwing error. I tried **[src]="img.ImagePath"** this method also I'm getting same response

[Console log. Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuFr.png)

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let img of imageData">
   <img [alt]="img.Name" src="{{img.ImagePath}}}">
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 getImages() {
   this.image.getImage().subscribe(res => {
   this.imageData = res;
    console.log(res);
 });
}
```

**service.ts**

```
  getImage() {
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44349/api/second?id=2');
  }
```

My API run in **https://localhost:44349/** and my angular application is running in **http://localhost:4200/**

Comment: Did you add your Images folder to "assets" in angular.json? https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have set up change detection it could be that your component is not being marked for check.

A better idea for handling asynchronous data with templates is to use the async pipe in the template

### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let img of (image.getImage() | async)">
  <img [alt]="img.Name" src="{{img.ImagePath}}}">
</div>
```

This will handle subscription and more importantly clean-up.
More reading:

- https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
- https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "not my image‘

Comment: my bad. I fixed it as below.
**<img src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}">**

Answer (score 0):

I just changes image URL to my API like below

```
 <img src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}">
```

Is it safe if I sue like this?

Answer (score -1):

> Hi,

> First thing, you should check for the path comming from the response.

> Second thing, if path for the images in response, then that image must be there in specified folder , here I think you have Images folder

> Third thing, showing 404 means you should check folder structure for image path where it resides and then check again, it will work>